# Show F is continuous at all points of [0,1) except at the nine reals

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F:[0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by $F(0.x_1x_2x_3...)=0.x_2x_3x_4...$ Show that $F$ is continuous at all points of $[0,1)$ except at the nine reals 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8 and 0.9.

I know this is true and I need to show it is continuous at certain points and not the others. I also know you can define the function as $F(f)(i)=f(i+1)$

Answer (score 1):

We note that
$$F(x)=10x\bmod1$$
and thus for all $x\in[0,1)$ except the nine multiples of 0.1, $F$ is continuous at $x$ by virtue of being $10x-k$ for some number $k\in[0,9]$ in a neighbourhood of $x$.

At the nine multiples of 0.1, the left and right limits of $F(x)$ do not agree, so $F$ is not continuous.

Comment: let us say for example we take $x=0.2$ how does a sequence from right and sequence from left look like.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician from left, it tends to 1; from right 0.